# How to return the validation values for a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a model validation such as

```
validates :my_number, 
  numericality: { 
    greater_than_or_equal_to: 1,
    less_than_or_equal_to: 300
  }
```

How can I read and e.g. display these values in the view?

```
MyModel.validators_on(:my_number).first.options[:on_or_before]
```

appears to be getting close. But this returns a file line reference, and I'm unsure how to manipulate this to return a value.

```
#<Proc:0x007fa5a3d3eb90@/Path/To/Project/app/models/my_model.rb:128 (lambda)>
```

Is there a convenient way of accessing these validation values and doing something in the view like

```
<p>This value must be between <%= @model.my_number.validation_greater_than %> and <%= @model.my_number.validation_less_than %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the limitations `1` & `300` in constants on the model and then access them in the view like:

```
... <%= ModelClass::MAX_MY_NUMBER % ... <%= ModelClass::MINIMUM_MY_NUMBER %> ...
```

and in the model validation like:

```
validates :my_number, 
  numericality: { 
    greater_than_or_equal_to: MINIMUM_MY_NUMBER,
    less_than_or_equal_to: MAX_MY_NUMBER
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @lazarus, this is a good idea. However gems such as simple_form are able to set max/min values on integer field by detecting the validation limits. I'm wondering how this gem achieves this? I've not (yet) been able to figure it out from the source, but will keep checking.